# Pickle error while creating new pyspark dataframe by processing old dataframe using foreach method

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Given a pyspark dataframe `given_df`, I need to use it to generate a new dataframe `new_df` from it.

I am trying to process the pyspark dataframe row by row using `foreach()` method. Lets say, for simplicity, both the dataframes `given_df` and `new_df` consists of a single column.

I have to process each row of this dataframe and based on the value present in that cell, I am creating some new Rows and adding it to `new_df` by `union`ing it with the Rows. The number of rows that are going to be generated upon processing a single row of `given_df` is variable.

```
new_df=spark.createDataFrame([], schema=['SampleField']) // Create an empty dataframe initially

given_df.foreach(func) // given_df already contains some data loaded. Now I run a function for each row.

def func(row):
    rows_to_append = getNewRowsAfterProcessingCurrentRow(row)
    global new_df // without this line, the next line will result in an error, because it will think that new_df is a local variable and we are trying to access it without defining it first.
    new_df=new_df.union(spark.createDataFrame(data=rows_to_append, schema=['SampleField'])
```

However this results in a pickle error.

If the union function is commented out, then no error takes place.

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 476, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 1097, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 356, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 789, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 500, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 729, in save_function_tuple
    save(state)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 843, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 500, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 729, in save_function_tuple
    save(state)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 843, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 500, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 729, in save_function_tuple
    save(state)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 843, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 500, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 729, in save_function_tuple
    save(state)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 846, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 500, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 729, in save_function_tuple
    save(state)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 846, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 500, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 729, in save_function_tuple
    save(state)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 846, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 495, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 729, in save_function_tuple
    save(state)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 524, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 356, in __getnewargs__
    "It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast "
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

For understanding a bit better what I am trying to do, let me give an example illustrating a possible use case :

Lets say `given_df` is a dataframe of sentences, where each sentence consist of some words separated by space.

```
given_df=spark.createDataframe([("The old brown fox",), ("jumps over",), ("the lazy log",)], schema=["SampleField"])
```

new_df is a dataframe consisting of each word at separate rows. So we will be processing each row of `given_df` and based on the words we get by splitting the row, we will be inserting each row into `new_df`.

```
new_df=spark.createDataFrame([("The",), ("old",), ("brown",), ("fox",), ("jumps",), ("over",), ("the",), ("lazy",), ("dog",)], schema=["SampleField"])
```

Comment: can  you give some example input and output? question is more abstract without it

Comment: Yes. Sure. Updated the question with sample input output

Comment: You're probably looking for `df.rdd.flatMap` rather than `df.foreach`. Perhaps you can do something like `df.rdd.flatMap(getNewRowsAfterProcessingCurrentRow).toDF()`

Comment: If you could add the code to create  `given_df` with some sample data and you add the expected output, I am pretty sure you will get an answer (probably I will be able to post it myself)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use DataFrame API on an executor which is not allowed and hence the `PicklingError`:

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

---

You should rewrite your code. You can for example use `RDD.flatMap` or, if you prefer the DataFrame API, `explode()` function.

Here is how you do it with the latter approach:

```py
given_df=spark.createDataFrame([("The old brown fox",), ("jumps over",), ("the lazy log",)], schema=["SampleField"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

@udf(returnType=ArrayType(StringType()))
def getNewRowsAfterProcessingCurrentRow(str):
  return str.split()

new_df= given_df\
  .select(explode(getNewRowsAfterProcessingCurrentRow("SampleField")).alias("SampleField"))\
  .unionAll(given_df)

new_df.show()
```

1. You wrap your `getNewRowsAfterProcessingCurrentRow()` in `udf()`. This just makes your function usable in DataFrame API.
2. Then, you use your function wrapped in another function called `explode()`. This is required since you want to "explode" (or transpose) the split sentences to multiple rows, a word per row.
3. Finally, you take the resulting DataFrame and union it with the original `given_df`.

The output:

```
+-----------------+
|      SampleField|
+-----------------+
|              The|
|              old|
|            brown|
|              fox|
|            jumps|
|             over|
|              the|
|             lazy|
|              log|
|The old brown fox|
|       jumps over|
|     the lazy log|
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Why cant I use dafaframe api on an executor ?

Comment: The reason I dont want to use map() function is that the input to the map() is a single row and the output is a single row. I need a case when the INPUT IS A SINGLE ROW BUT OUTPUT OF THE FUNCTION MAY BE MULTIPLE ROWS.

The reason I dont want to use explode is that it is not general enough
 like map.

I preferred foreach because here I am at a liberty to process each row, however way I like. And inside the function no one cares what I return.